# Not able to return a json file PHP

Tags: php, json

I am not able to return a json file doing an echo or print_r. This is my code:

```
<?php

include 'logFolder.php';   

 $email = "48k2r4l6o60nbn2cug9p0luk7c@group.calendar.google.com";
 $url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
 //echo $url;
 $xml = file_get_contents($url);

 $feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 $i = 0;
 $ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);
 $text = '[';

 foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
    $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
    $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();
    $start=$when_atr['startTime'];
    $end=$when_atr['endTime'];
$url = $entry->link->attributes();
$url = $url['href'];
    $title=addslashes($entry->title);
if($i > 0){
    $text = $text . ',';
}
   $text = $text . '{"date":"'.$start.'","type":"meeting","title":"'.$title.'","description":" ","url":"'.$url.'"}';


 // $text[$i] = array("date"=>$start, "type"=>"meeting", "title"=>$title, "description"=>" ", "url"=>$url); 
$File = $logFolder . 'ajson' . '.json' ;
$fh = fopen($File, 'a') or die();
fwrite($fh, '{"date":"'.$start.'","type":"meeting","title":"'.$title.'","description":" ","url":"'.$url.'"}');
fclose($fh);


}
$text = $text . ']';    

echo $text; 


?>
```

I am reading events from a google calendar and I want to include some info in my json file. I can save it to a file as you can see in my code, so the variabes has the correct content. But, each time I want to print it in the screen or return it in echo, I get nothing printed. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Don't hand-craft your JSON string. Use `json_encode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays and json_encode();

```
include 'logFolder.php';   

$email = "48k2r4l6o60nbn2cug9p0luk7c@group.calendar.google.com";
$url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
//echo $url;
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$i = 0;
$ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);
$data = array();
foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
    $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
    $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();
    $start=$when_atr['startTime'];
    $end=$when_atr['endTime'];
    $url = $entry->link->attributes();
    $url = $url['href'];
    $title=addslashes($entry->title);

    $data[] = array( 'date' => $start, 'type' => 'meeting', 'title' => $title, 'description', 'url' => $url);
}

$json = json_encode($data);
$File = $logFolder . 'ajson' . '.json' ;

$fh = fopen($File, 'a') or die();
fwrite($fh,$json);
fclose($fh);

echo $json;
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried it? it doesn't show anything on screen for me. Thats my problem

Comment: No, I don't know how to use error reporting. I noticed that after foreach, nothing is executed. you can test adding an echo right after the }

Comment: Why do you use multi dimensional array for `$data`?

Comment: [This describes how to force errors to show on screen or log them to a file.](http://itslennysfault.com/force-php-to-show-all-errors-or-save-them-to-a-log-for-trouble-shooting)

Comment: This is the error I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in /var/www/Test/server/getJSON.php on line 16

Comment: $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes(); Error means: when[0] is not an object. It's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_encode.

In your code it would be like this saving each entry individually as a file and outputting the total json (as your code above attempts to do)...

```
<?php
    include 'logFolder.php';   
    $email = "48k2r4l6o60nbn2cug9p0luk7c@group.calendar.google.com";
    $url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);

    //init new array
    $jsonArray=array();
    foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
        $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
        $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();
        $start=$when_atr['startTime'];
        $end=$when_atr['endTime'];
        $url = $entry->link->attributes();
        $url = $url['href'];
        $title=addslashes($entry->title);
        //create local json array
        $thisJson=array(
            'date'=>$start,
            'type'=>'meeting',
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=> ' ' ,
            'url' => $url
        );
        //add local json array to big json array
        $jsonArray[]=$thisJson
        $File = $logFolder . 'ajson' . '.json' ;
        $fh = fopen($File, 'a') or die();
        //save json this json array as text
        fwrite($fh, json_encode($thisJson));
        fclose($fh);
    }

    //output compiled json array
    echo(json_encode($jsonArray));
?>
```

One thing In otice is that your fopen uses the smae file name every time so it's just overwriting itself over and over. NOt sure why you're doing this but if you wanted a single file containing all of the json you need to do it after the loop like this...

```
<?php
    include 'logFolder.php';   
    $email = "48k2r4l6o60nbn2cug9p0luk7c@group.calendar.google.com";
    $url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/".$email."/public/full";
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $ns=$feed->getNameSpaces(true);

    //init new array
    $jsonArray=array();
    foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
        $when=$entry->children($ns["gd"]);
        $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();
        $start=$when_atr['startTime'];
        $end=$when_atr['endTime'];
        $url = $entry->link->attributes();
        $url = $url['href'];
        $title=addslashes($entry->title);
        //create local json array
        $thisJson=array(
            'date'=>$start,
            'type'=>'meeting',
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=> ' ' ,
            'url' => $url
        );
        //add local json array to big json array
        $jsonArray[]=$thisJson
    }

    //output compiled json array
    echo(json_encode($jsonArray));

    //save the json
    $File = $logFolder . 'ajson' . '.json' ;
    $fh = fopen($File, 'a') or die();
    //save json this json array as text
    fwrite($fh, json_encode($jsonArray));
    fclose($fh);    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I put fopen to check if something was been read. In final version it will dissapear. After foreach, nothing is executed.

Answer (score 0):

you have a simple error - `$i` is never incremented, so you are missing "," in the generated output, thus it's illegal json syntax.

in your `foreach` loop, add:

```
$i++;
```

before the loop closes.

---

but I also agree that using `json_encode()` is better, but **slower**

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add $i in stackoverflow version code. It was in mine. The problem is that after foreach, nothing is executed

Comment: in that case either you  have php error or: $File = $logFolder . 'ajson' . '.json' ;
$fh = fopen($File, 'a') or die(); <-- you cannot open file for editing. check permissions.

Comment: The problem is in the first line of foreach, I don't know why.

Comment: try:         $when=$entry->children(gd); also add on very  top: ini_set("display_errors", "on"); that should help find cause. seems you have invalid xml structure or the way you access it.

Comment: This is the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in /var/www/Test/server/getJSON.php on line 15. Line 15 has: $when_atr=$when->when[0]->attributes();

Comment: clearly this means that there is no such object "when[0]". do var_dump($when) to see what resides in it. so problem is not in the json as you asked in question but in your xml structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
{

    $codes = Array(
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        306 => '(Unused)',
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

    return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}


function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/json')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;


}
```

try to use these function while returning a json i will create a downloadable file of your json in localhost

Comment: Where do I have to put these functions and how do I call them in php script?